# mysql sytax error near the if conditiion

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS discount$
CREATE PROCEDURE discount(IN price INT, OUT price_after_discount INT)
BEGIN
  IF (price<100) THEN
       SET price_after_discount=price;
  ELSEIF(price>100 AND price<200) THEN
      SET price_after_discount=(price*0.10)+price;
  ELSE
     SET price_after_discount=(price*0.20)+price;
   END IF;
END$
DELIMITER;
```

Mysql tells me that I have an error on line 9:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

Why do I have an error? what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are missing `END IF`. See manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE discount(IN price INT, OUT price_after_discount INT)
BEGIN
  IF (price<100) THEN
       SET price_after_discount=price;
  ELSEIF(price>100 AND price<200) THEN
      SET price_after_discount=(price*0.10)+price;//Error here
  ELSE
     SET price_after_discount=(price*0.20)+price;
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Generally `near '' at line no` this kind of error comes in case of missing something in statements like `IF ELSE .. or BEGIN .. END` clauses, which doesn't tell exact line number and piece of code.

EDIT: You are missing space between this `DELIMITER ;`

Comment: okay.. i think you found the answer..but see my update.. damn..i have a delimiter problem

Comment: you are missing space between this `DELIMITER ;`